# Why integer key do not work in HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

Cobnsider the following code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Map<Number, String> map = new HashMap<Number, String>();
    map.put(1L, "test");
    System.out.println(map.get(1));
}
```

Why HashMap.get returns null? O_o It must return value for any object which hashCode function returns 1, is not it?

**UPDATED**

The problem is Map interface receives Object, not parameterized type. So I expected that any object can be a key, but HashMap implementation check type with equals, it was surprising for me.

**And autoboxing is not** the problem. I know, that 1 became Integer, and 1L to Long. But they have **same** hashcode. So as I thought any implementation Map#get should return value for any Object with **same** hashcode.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(map.get(1L));`

Comment: You are right that Integer 1 and Long 1L have the same hash code and would be stored in the same bucket inside the map. But then `.equals` is done and returns false.

Answer (score 6):

You're putting a key of 1L (`Long`) and getting a key of 1 (`Integer`).

They're not the same thing, so be careful.

Either remove the L from the put, or add the L to the get. Or even better, don't write them out as primitives and rely on autoboxing.

Comment: Or do not use HashMap<Number, String> but HashMap<Long, String> instead

Comment: @TwoThe Indeed, I didn't even pay attention to that.

Answer (score 1):

There is a type mismatch between putting and getting.

What happens here is AutoBoxing, Java will perform conversion between primitives to its `Object` equivalents and vice-versa for you automatically  rather than via the `new()`, So  became `Integer` and another is `Long`.

Try the below ways:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<Number, String> map = new HashMap<Number, String>();
        map.put(1L, "test");
        System.out.println(map.get(1L));
    }
```

Or

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<Number, String> map = new HashMap<Number, String>();
        map.put(1, "test");
        System.out.println(map.get(1));
    }
```

Though both have same `value`(1) but of different objects they are not `equal`,

```
i.e. Integer(1) != Long(1).
```

That is the problem here, which is being happened by using Auto-boxing.

A quick example

```
        Long l = new Long(1);
        Integer i = new Integer(1);
        System.out.println(i.equals(l)); //false -->Hashmap get() failed here
        System.out.println(i.intValue() ==l.intValue());//true
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're not passing a Long type of key when retrieving the value, but an integer instead. These get autoboxed as different objects and therefore do not represent the same key.

Answer (score 1):

Integers and Longs are not the same.

`Integer#equals`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

`Long#equals`

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I spot the problem, see java.util.HashMap#get source code, it contains:

```
public V get(Object key) {
        if (key == null)
            return getForNullKey();
        int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
        for (Entry<K,V> e = table[indexFor(hash, table.length)];
             e != null;
             e = e.next) {
            Object k;
            if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
                return e.value;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

So it check key with equals before returning the value.

Comment: What is the problem with java.util.HashMap#get?

Comment: Actually your problem is not with `get` It meant as why equals fails ? That is because of `Auto boxing` :)